# Skipping C++ global destructors

Tags: c++, destructor, exit

Is there a way to either suppress the generation of destructors for global objects (in particular those of collection types such as `vector` and `unordered_map`), or to exit a program without calling such destructors (but still flushing stdout, as I gather `abort` does not do)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [quick_exit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/quick_exit) and _Exit.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do that is to create them on the heap, and never release :

```
std::vector< int > *doNotCallDestructor = new std::vector< int >;
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the sort of problem that can be solved robustly with *initialization on demand*.

```
std::vector<int> & get_my_vector () {
    static std::vector<int> *vec;
    if (vec) return *vec;
    return *(vec = new std::vector<int>);
}
```

In a multi-threaded context, you can use "double checked locking" to initialize the static, or if you have C++11, the following is guaranteed to be thread-safe:

```
std::vector<int> & get_my_vector () {
    static std::vector<int> *vec = new std::vector<int>;
    return *vec;
}
```

Initialization on demand provides the following benefits:

- Lazy initialization of globals -- this means that if a global is not used, no memory will be allocated for it. Traditional globals occupy resources at the get-go.
- Immunity to shared library initialization dependencies -- this means if one shared library wants to use the global of another shared library, the Singleton pattern triggers the code to do the initialization of that global on demand. Traditional globals may not yet be initialized when accessed from a different shared library.

Initialization on demand is the same technique used to instantiate a singleton in the Singleton pattern. As we are not limiting the number of instances of `vector<int>` this idiom is not a Singleton in any sense.

Comment: Actually, the initialization order fiasco can strike as you as you have globals into two different translation units (source files), no need to involve libraries at all.

Comment: That's not a singleton, it's just a local static (which is better, it doesn't prevent others from creating a vector<int> if they want to)

Comment: I'm not sure "robust" is the right word, since this isn't thread-safe. `static std::vector<int> * vec = new std::vector<int>; return *vec;` would be better, as long as your compiler guarantees thread-safe initialisation of local statics (which a C++11 compiler must).

Comment: @JonathanWakely: It is true it is not a singleton in the single instance sense. I was using the pattern to ensure initialization safety. Regards.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: For thread safety, I would have normally used a regular mutex, and so the initialization would fall into the "double checked locking". With C++11, I would assign to the static the result of a `new` call, then. Regards.

Comment: It's not a singleton in any sense, it's just a global. Singleton is a bad pattern, avoid it, and don't misapply the name to useful idioms.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Roger that. Edit has been made. Thanks and regards